# When deploying Sitecore in Azure, how do you fix (or prevent) a slot lock?

Tags: azure, deployment

We are deploying a `Sitecore` web application via CI/CD in `Octopus` to an `Azure Staging slot`.

The deployment randomly fails with the following error:

```
 New-AzureRMWebAppSlot : Cannot acquire exclusive lock to create, update or  
 At C:\Octopus\Work\20180727035133-565589-870\Script.ps1:5 char:1 
 + New-AzureRMWebAppSlot -Name TestCM -Slot Staging -ResourceGroupNam ... 
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
 + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmWebAppSlot], CloudException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.WebApps.Cmdlets.DeploymentSlots.NewAzureWebAppSlotCmdlet 
The remote script failed with exit code 1 
The action Create and Deploy Staging Slot CM on the Octopus Server failed
```

The error does not always occur.

I followed microsoft's [docs on checking for locks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-lock-resources) in `Azure Portal` and none are showing up.

How do I fix (or prevented) this issue ?

Comment: Did you stop staging slot before deployment? We use VSTS to do this and never had such issues.
We stop, deploy and start staging slot and swap.

Comment: I forgot, after stopping slot we have "Wait" step set to 60 seconds. Sometimes slot is not fully stopped even the stop command returns.

Comment: Someone else mentioned this to me and I confirmed that the staging slots was stopped before retrying (waited 5 minutes between attempts).  The same issue persisted. I also tried stopping the main web app as well as all slots and still the same issue.    The lock seems to be persisting in the background for a number of hours.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about sitecore

Comment: Other Sitecore devs do seem to be hitting this issue.  Other questions within the Azure tag along the same lines.  e.g. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7816/how-to-copy-complete-site-from-production-slot-to-staging-slot-in-azure-paas